# Find & Run program.exe and add "/repair" to line. (BatchFile)

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

So the aim is to :
1) find the steam.exe on the C drive. (This part is working fine)
2) run steam.exe with the "/repair" on the end.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s c:\steam.exe') do "%%~fi **/repair**"
pause
exit
```

This attempt returns "The directory name is invalid" So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... do "%%~fi /repair"
```

tries to start a program named `"...\steam.exe /repair"` Surely, you want to start the program `"...\steam.exe"` with the parameter `/repair` (last qoute at the wrong place), so it should be:

```
... do "%%~fi" /repair
```

Comment: Doh! that simple XD ty.